# $\sum_{n \geq 0} a_n z^n$; $z=R$ is singular

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $\sum_{n \geq 0} a_n z^n$ with radius of convergence $R >0$. Show that if all the $a_n$ are positive, then the point $z=R$ is singular.

I found that $\sum_{n \geq 0} a_n R^n \geq \min\{a_n : n \in \mathbb{N}\} \sum_{n \geq 0}  R^n$. Is it a mistake of the book that $R$ have to be greater than $0$? I think $R$ have to be greater than $1$. Am I right?

Comment: $\sum_n a_n r^n$ converges for $r < R$ but diverges for $r > R$. together with $a_n \ge 0$  you get $\lim_{r \to R^-} \sum_n a_n r^n = +\infty$. hint : use that  $\sum_n a_n r^n$ is increasing on $[0,R[$, and consider two cases : the case where it is bounded on $[0,R[$, and the case where it is not.

Comment: (and what you wrote is false)

Comment: Why this is not true?

Comment: try yourself, with $e^z$, $\frac{1}{1-z}$, and also $\sin 4 z$, $\frac{1}{1-z^k}$, etc.

Comment: I show the second part of your hint, but how could I show that $\lim_{r \to R^-} \sum_n a_n r^n = +\infty$ if $\sum_n a_n r^n \leq M(r)$? I suppose  I have to show that $M(r) \to \infty$ if $t \to \infty$, but how?

Comment: if $f(r) = \sum_n a_n r^n$ is bounded on $[0,R[$, because it is increasing, then $f'(r)$ is also bounded on $[0,R[$, and by induction all the other derivatives, i.e. $f(z)$ and each of its derivatives are bounded  on $|z| < R$ hence by continuity also on $|z| \le R$. this proves that the radius of convergence of $\sum_n a_n z^n$ has to be greater than $R$ $\,^{(*)}$, a contradiction.
($\,^{(*)}$ do you know the Cauchy integral formula ?)